# Qt app crash when opening ODBC db

Tags: c++, sql, qt, odbc

I'm developing an application which connects with an external ODBC database.
When I run it on Qt, everything works fine, but when I try to opened standalone it always crash on m_db->open().

When app crashes it throughs this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the code:

```
m_db = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","edb"));
m_db->setDatabaseName(m_line);
m_db->open(); // <-// app crash here!
```

Where:

```
m_line = "Driver=/opt/sqlanywhere12/lib64/libdbodbc12.so;CommLinks=tcpip(Host=ip;port=port);ServerName=db;DatabaseName=db;Uid=uid;Pwd=psswd;"
```

Anyone has some clue?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 64bits.
Thanks,

**EDIT**

Well, after some more testing, it seems it stops crashing if I remove the driver configuration from the m_line variable, but obviously, it stop working...

**EDIT2**

After configure a custom run from Qt creator, it says the breaking point is 0x7ffff6a777b9 on disassembler. What does it mean?

Comment: Since `m_db` is a pointer, what is the value of it?  Does it point to a valid instance?  And why a pointer?  Why not write a simple test app using an object instance (not a pointer), so as to verify that the simple app works?

Comment: Yes, it's a valid pointer. I've added a piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the stupidest pitfall ever...
I forget to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH on execute.

Answer (score 1):

That is *not* how you use `QSqlDatabase`.  `QSqlDatabase` instances are handles to internal connections retrievable by connection name, they do not control the connection's lifetime.
So it should be declared on the [stack](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#details):

```
m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","edb"));
m_db.setDatabaseName(m_line);     
m_db.open();
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunatly, after apply your suggested changes, the program still crash at the same point.
Moreover, I need a pointer due to the internal management.

I think the problem should be that when Qt run the app, it add some configuration parameters I don't (like adding some include path). As per my last updated, the problem is that the anywhere library crash when it is launch outside Qt.

Comment: @Atron What does your debugger say?

Comment: In fact, nothing. Program work when when it's launch on Qt Creator (even on release mode). The problems come when I try to launch it on terminal or by clicking on the executable.
Thanks again @cmannett85!

Comment: @Atron "I need a pointer due to the internal management" No you don't.  `m_db` should not be a pointer, it should be initialised with a `QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(..)` and destroyed with `QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(..), both using "edb" as the connection identifier.  So it seems that your real problem is that the ODBC driver isn't in a place where your application can find it when outside of Qt Creator.

Comment: If the odbc db is not avaliable, gui get freeze for 3-4 seconds since the program try to reconnect with the database, to avoid that, I sent the db pointer to another thread and tried to open the db on it. When db is opened, a signal is sent to the main thread and extra thread is closed.
I didn't want to mention that in order to don't get people confused beacuse the problems is not the thread but the way the qsl driver is opened outside Qt. Right now I only have open create a QSqlDatabase instance and try to open the database.
If I don't use a pointer, the problem is not solved. :(